# Background processes using bash aliases in the .bashrc file

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create an alias that can start a process (indicated in the parameter $1) on the background.

For achieve this I'm trying adding this lane to the .bashrc file:

alias launchprocess='$1 &'

And the problem is that the process used as the parameter 1 is not launched on the background.

Does somebody knows how to achieve this?

Comment: aliases do not accept parameters.  Use a function.

Comment: actually, if I use only:
alias launchprocess='$1' 
and then run in the terminal: launchprocess xlogo 
It executes the process but in the foreground. Therefore, aliases accept parameters.

Comment: No.  When you use that alias, the text `launchprocess` is replaced by the text `$1`, so your command becomes `$1 xlogo`.  Since `$1` is almost certainly the empty string, that is the same as merely typing `xlogo`.  Aliases do not take parameters.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Thank you very much. I'll try it with a function. By the way, Is there any document that explain all about aliases and functions?